# How do I let users with a certain role add nodes but use the front end theme (not the admin theme)

Tags: users

I have a role that allows users to create nodes themselves. What is the standard practice way to let them add nodes but not see the administration theme (I am using adminimal), and rather use a different theme on the node/add page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Role Theme Switcher](https://drupal.org/project/role_theme_switcher) seems to be what you need:

> Useful Drupal module to assign separate themes for different roles (including anonymous) in your system.
>
> Often you want to separate Drupal administrative interface from frontend. You can do this assigning appropriate theme for you as user. What to do if you want to show different theme for non-authorized user?

Comment: so which is the best one then?

Comment: "Best one" depends on way to many factors to be reliably answered and will vary from reader to reader as their situations will always be a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

For a *very* simple, module free solution, you could either:

1. Disable the `Use the administration theme when editing or creating content` option in `admin/appearance`.
2. Remove the `View the administration theme` permission for the role in `admin/people/permissions`